# SQLite schema, database size, access speed, updates doubts

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app, i'm planning to store data locally to reduce data usage of internet and allowing offline access also. My current schema contains 9 columns. Out of which 2 columns are for storing urls, one for plain text of 140 chars, 1 for datetime, 2 for plain text of 100 chars, 3 other for integers. Number of records to be inserted is depend on user ie how much records he wants. He can delete them whenever he wants. Multiple records are to inserted one time. Same with deletion.
Now my question is, will this cause app overload in terms of insertions, deletion and maintenance?  I first thought of storing this data in filesystem (xml file) but then deletion of records can be difficult. So should I go for SQLite approach or xml file as storage. Other solutions are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend SQLite over xml for what you are wanting to do. SQLite is going to be faster and easier IMHO. I have done reads from both. Never done inserts and updates.

the xml file would have to be openned, then parsed to get any data out of it, the closed :0) You are correct as well deletes, updates, inserts would be a lot more difficult with an xml file.

Comment: the thing is, i'm using local storage as cache as well for images downloaded from server. if SD card is available it'll be used, if not internal mem is used. There is no bound how much images are downloaded and above insertions on sqlite database as it is user's choice. But at same time, i don't want my app to do not responding or take too much time doing all this.

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with Android development, but I use AsyncTask to make sure those things can happen has fast as possible and don't tie up your UI thread (continue responding). Also, you can have locations for images and other files in your database stored on SD card or internal memory.

Comment: You might also consider using a Service to do some of the work when the device is not in use...

Comment: = yes, i'm familiar with AsyncTask. In fact, i'm using it to download xml from server and then threads to download images. You're right I should go for SQLite. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes yes yes, I would absolutely say go for SQLite. The schema you've described is actually pretty modest and the usage patterns you've outlined are nothing significant.

SQLite is designed to be able to persist fairly significant amounts of data on the device's storage in an efficient manner. This would certainly be preferable to storing the data in XML which is not a particularly efficient format and is an order of magnitude slower when you consider attempting to obtain a single record.

I myself have written apps which contain over 15 different tables with >10 columns per table, a requirement Sqlite handles comfortably.